# VBA Custom class does not capture events

Tags: class, events, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a class that manages the events of a combo box in Access 2010. Here you have the code:

**Class TestEvents**

```
Public WithEvents cbMyCombo As Access.ComboBox

Public Property Get AssociatedCombo() As Access.ComboBox
    Set AssociatedCombo = cbMyCombo
End Property

Public Sub cbMyCombo_Change()
    MsgBox "Combo has changed!"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set cbMyCombo = Form_Form1.Combo1
End Sub
```

**Form1 Code** (Contains a combobox named Combo1)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private MyTestEvents As TestEvents

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set MyTestEvents = New TestEvents
   MsgBox MyTestEvents.AssociatedCombo.Name
End Sub
```

When running the code, I get (as expected) a message with the combobox name (Combo1), so the TestEvents.AssociatedCombo property is pointing to the right object **but** nothing happens when I change the combo value. I would expect to get the message "Combo has changed".

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: How many values you have in Combo box ? Combo box change will happen only if more than 1 value in combo box

Comment: Thanks Logan; it has 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default events sunk for a form control are not raised in VBA at all; to enable them (and subsequently enable your `WithEvents`) you need to wire up each event you want to handle;

```
Set cbMyCombo = Form_Form1.Combo1 '//please put this in a property!

cbMyCombo.OnKeyDown = "[Event Procedure]"
cbMyCombo.OnBlaDeBla = "[Event Procedure]"
```

(Note that's the actual string value you need to set, not a placeholder/example)

You can also do this on the Events tab of the control properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Alex. Problem then is that the [Event Procedure] needs to be outside of the class, isn't? Should be a public function in a separate module.

Comment: No, if you add `cbMyCombo.OnChange = "[Event Procedure]"` to your class what you have should work

Comment: THANKS! By putting literally "[Event Procedure]" everything works. I misinterpreted it as a kind of placeholder for the name of the procedure linked with the event. Again, thanks :)